# antd datepicker how to make variable for return in const?

Tags: reactjs, datatable, jsx, antd

Hi i'm newbie frontend developer....

question is below down

1. how to make return a in const onChange?
2. if possible what is matter?

```
import React from 'react'
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';

var a = "";

const onChange = ( date, dateString ) => {
  console.log( dateString )
  return a = ( dateString )
};
export const monthval = () => {
  return a
};
const MonthPicker = () => {

  return (
    <>
        <DatePicker onChange={onChange} picker="month" 
                    
        />
    </>    
    )
}

export default MonthPicker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in react to save changing values, we use states. To save the date we need to create a state. and change it each time the onChange function calls. We create the state inside the component

```
const [date, setDate] = useState();
```

and In the on change you need to call the set function.

```
const onChange = ( date, dateString ) => {
   setDate(dateString)
};
```

would recommend checking states out and what they are here.
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usestate.asp